# Stop My Footer From Sitting On The Bottom Of The Screen

Tags: html, css

I'm having an issue with my footer where it is being stuck to the bottom of my screen and not sitting at the bottom of the page, can anyone help me sit at the bottom on the page not on the bottom of the screen?

```css
footer {
  position: fixed;
  left: 0px;
  bottom: 0px;
  height: 70px;
  width: 100%;
  background: #2c2c2c;
}

#footer_container {
  max-width: 940px;
  height: 70px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding-top: 2%;
}

.social {
  list-style-type: none;
}

.social li a {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  display: inline;
  float: right;
  padding: 10px;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  font-weight: bolder;
}

.social>li>a:hover {
  color: #D9D9D9
}

.copyright_text {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -10px;
  left: 0;
  padding-top: 2%;
  float: left;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 0.30cm;
  color: #fff;
  margin-left: 20px;
}

.logo_footer {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  position: fixed;
  left: 0px;
  bottom: 15px;
  height: 50px;
  width: 100%;
  margin-left: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}
```

```html
<footer>
  <div id="footer_container">
    <img src="images/logo.png" title="AccountPanda" style="width:112.5px;height:37.5px;" class="logo_footer">
    <p class="copyright_text">&copy; Copyright 2017 AccountPARADISE</p>
    <ul class="social">
      <li><a href="https://twitter.com/accountparadise" target="_blank">TWITTER</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>

</footer>
```

Comment: If you want it to stick at the bottom of the page you shouldn't use `position:fixed` as this will make it keep sticking at a certain position on the screen.

Comment: @phpheini what should be used instead?

Comment: what is happening once you removed it?

Answer (score 0):

If you use position:fixed; then your element will be casted to the location depended on your screen, not your page.

If you want to trow it down you can do multiple things. You can have a parent container with position relative en put absolute bottom:0.

Or just place it display block and put it below your other html containers.

This way it will be aligned behind the rest and at the bottom of your page.

Answer (score 0):

Just don't use `position: fixed` - erase that from the CSS rule for the footer, then it will simply be below all other elements above it. (The `left` and `bottom` parameters can also be erased in this case, they are only relevant for "positioned" elements)

Comment: I dont under stand what you mean

Comment: What's so difficult? Erase/delete `position: fixed` from the `footer` CSS rule.

Comment: Ok i only now have the issue of the body not being the full size of the page i set it to have height: 100%; but doesnt accomplish this

Comment: add `html, body (height: 100%; } ` to your CSS